# Conditional creation of Variable using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new var "PERIOD" based on dates. The sample data is given below:

```
Date
1/10/2012
1/11/2012
1/12/2012
1/13/2012
1/14/2012
1/15/2012
1/16/2012
1/17/2012
1/18/2012
```

After conditioning the new dataset looks like:

```
  Date      PERIOD
1/10/2012     Y1
1/11/2012     Y1
1/12/2012     Y1
1/13/2012     Y1
1/14/2012     Y1
1/15/2012     Y2
1/16/2012     Y2
1/17/2012     Y2
1/18/2012     Y2
```

The code I was using is

```
dat$PERIOD<-{If '1/10/2012' <=  as.Date(dat$Date) <= '1/14/2012' dat$PERIOD='Y1' else
    If '1/15/2012' <=  as.Date(dat$Date) <= '1/18/2012'dat$PERIOD='Y2'
}
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in dat$PERIOD<-{If '1/10/2012'
```

Thank you. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see `?as.Date` for correct date format. 
Your conditional statement is mostly wrong. R is case sensitive. You have to use `if`. Please find some example code below:

```
d <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(paste(2012, 1, 10:18, sep="/")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d$PERIOD <- ifelse(as.Date("2012/1/15") > d$Date, "Y1", "Y2")
```